# getting value from stdclass object/array

Tags: php, arrays, json, stdclass

ive been trying for a while now trying to get a value from this std object

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'regions' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 1,
       'name' => 'Canada',
       'image_url' => 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/staticimageskiind/flags/CA@3x.png',
    )),
    1 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 2,
       'name' => 'USA',
       'image_url' => 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/staticimageskiind/flags/US@3x.png',
    )),
    2 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 3,
       'name' => 'Global',
       'image_url' => 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/staticimageskiind/flags/GLBL@3x.png',
    )),
    3 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 4,
       'name' => 'Australia',
       'image_url' => 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/staticimageskiind/flags/AU@3x.png',
    )),
  ),
   'info' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'code' => 'INFO_MARKETPLACE_RETRIEVED_REGIONS',
     'name' => 'Marketplace Regions Retrieved',
     'message' => 'A list of marketplace regions has been retrieved.',
  )),
));
```

but i can't seem to get a value from this object, help would be appreciated, ive searched online but couldnt find out a solution

Comment: i think you are using drupal , try with  $VARIABLE->__get('regions');

Comment: Do you tried to use `$object->regions` ? If not try to give more informations about what you already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try:

```
echo $object->regions[0]->name;
```

For example?

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to get the correct output i wanted by

```
$abc = $result->regions;
echo $abc[1]->name;
```

hope this helps anyone in need